# At what point do closed questions disappear from general view?

Tags: support, closing-questions

The question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5523/ , for example, was quickly closed as "pure advertising," which it is.  Nevertheless it still appears among the list of questions and thereby serves its intended purpose of spamming this community.  Thus closing appears to be an ineffective resolution.  What *effective* options do we have to counter such abuses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to admit that I would have deleted the question (and the possibly even the user) as it is blatant spam.

I agree that we shouldn't just delete closed questions, but in this case it is just spam.

Comment: It it was closed as blatant spam, it should have been deleted, too. Technically, the mod should have just flagged it as spam which would have had the same effect.

Comment: Together, this reply and @Robert Cartaino's comment clarify the situation.  Thank you to both.

Comment: I just deleted the question (flagged as spam, as suggested).  I suppose it wasn't clear to me that it was *blatant* spam at the time, since it was somewhat relevant to the site topic.  But I can see how keeping it around would be bad in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

It will disappear from the main page after enough other questions have been edited to replace it.

I think this is actually a feature since it allows the community to *see* closed questions, and hence be part of the debate around whether they are on-topic, etc.

Comment: I understand the merits of this, but couldn't there be an exception for blatant spam?

Comment: Well, I could have deleted the question altogether.  But I still don't see the harm in having it on the front page as an example.  I can see why you might want this, but FWIW, I think the current arrangement is best.  Once you're elected moderator in this coming election, you can take a hard line on these ones.  :)

Comment: I think I can safely elude being elected: don't people have to nominate themselves? ;-)  I'm perfectly happy with the current moderators.

Answer (score 1):

If leaving the post around is harmful (i.e. language, illegal content, blatant spam, etc), it should be deleted by the moderator immediately. But if it is simply closed as something like off-topic, the ability to "vote to delete" will appear after a few days (10K user power).